# Configure correct routing for folder and file with the same naming on IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have site hosted IIS with hidden extentions
using this rule

```
            <rule name="Hide .html ext">
                <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*).html"/>
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
```

The main problem is that i have file that without extension has same naming that one of my folder
for example 
wwwroot/page.html
wwwroot/page/page.html

When this rule applying server return 
403 - Forbidden on when i call www.test.com/page 
and all works fine when i call www.test.com/page/page
Is it possible to configure url rewrite module to correct work with both of this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some workaround for that problem. If you will delete this condition: `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>`

Then your HTML page will work for this url `www.test.com/page` and `www.test.com/page/page` but will not for `www.test.com/page/` (it will return forbidden).

If `page.html` is single exception in your system and you will not have the same collisions, then you can also do in another way, create the additional rule for your url. Just add this rule before `Hide .html ext` rule:

```
<rule name="Exception for page" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(page)(\/?)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

In this case, all URLs will work correctly:

- `www.test.com/page`
- `www.test.com/page/`
- `www.test.com/page/page`